# Why is my recaptcha regester form being spammed?

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha

Here is the URL to the form: http://www.mrhowtosay.com/register

I seem to be getting about 20-30 machine generated accounts being made from this form. I don't know how the bots are getting through it because I tested it numerous times to see if it would go through without entering the correct recaptcha, but it seems to properly reject account creation attempts with blank or incorrect recaptcha when I try it.

So I don't know how to stop the spam accounts from being created. Perhaps my public key has been compromised? From the pattern I see in the spam created accounts, it seems that there is more than one source creating them.

In case it's necessary, here is the code from the `doregister.php` page that the form posts to:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
</head>
<body>Please wait...
<?
session_start();
include 'functions.php';
function check_email_address($email) {
// First, we check that there's one @ symbol, 
// and that the lengths are right.
if (!ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)) {
// Email invalid because wrong number of characters 
// in one section or wrong number of @ symbols.
return false;
}
// Split it into sections to make life easier
$email_array = explode("@", $email);
$local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
if
(!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&
?'*+/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$",
$local_array[$i])) {
  return false;
}
}
// Check if domain is IP. If not, 
// it should be valid domain name
if (!ereg("^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$", $email_array[1])) {
$domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
    return false; // Not enough parts to domain
}
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
  if
(!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|
?([A-Za-z0-9]+))$",
$domain_array[$i])) {
    return false;
  }
}
}
return true;
}


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------checkrecaptcha

require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "CENSORED";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        $_SESSION['msg2'] = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Please try it again";
        ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/register"> <?
die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} 

else{
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification



    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------------uthenticating submied fields---------------------------
    //--------------------------------------------check passwords match--------------------------------------------------
    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['repeat'])  
    {
        $_SESSION['msg2'] = "passwords dont match";
        ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $password = $_POST['password'];     
    }//--------------------------------------------check passwords match----END----------------------------------------------
    if ($_POST['email'])//-------------------------check email was submited--------------------------------------------------
    {   
        if(!check_email_address($_POST['email']))
        {
            $_SESSION['msg2'] = "(".$_POST['email'].") is not a valid email";
            ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit();
        }
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['msg2'] = "email is a required field";
        ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit();
    }//-------------------------check email was submited------END--------------------------------------------
    if ($_POST['name'])//-------------------------check name was submited--------------------------------------------------
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['msg2'] = "name is a required field";
        ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit();
    }//-------------------------check name was submited----------END----------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------uthenticating submited fields-------END--------------------


             //connecting to mysql server
        $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mrhowtos_user", "9Xhe9e949Xhe9e94!");
        mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");


        //error handling
        if (!$DBConnect)

        echo "<p>the database server is not available</P>";

        else
        {//------------------------------------------checking for existing user confilcts---------------------------
            if (mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "mrhowtos_main"))
            {
                $checkqwry1 = "select name from users where name = '$name';";
                $checkqwry2 = "select email from users where email = '$email';";
                $array = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $checkqwry1);
                $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($array);
                if ($Row)
                {
                    $_SESSION['msg2'] = $Row[0]." is already in use by another user";
                    ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit();
                }

                $array = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $checkqwry2);
                $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($array);

                if ($Row)
                {
                    $_SESSION['msg2'] = "the email ".$Row[0]." is already in use by another user";
                    ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit();
                }
                else//------------------------------------------checking for existing user confilcts----END-----------------------
                {   
                    //-------------------------------aproved account credentials, insert in db and login-----------------------------------
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
                    $_SESSION['rights'] = 1;
                    $_SESSION['msg2'] = "hi ".$name." you have successfully registered! and logged in!<br />Note that the \"Make Translations\" Option has now appeared in the Naviation so you can start adding translations!";
                    $ip = getRealIpAddr();
                    //--------------------------------------------insert user into db--------------------------------------------------------
                        $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, "INSERT INTO `mrhowtos_main`.`users` (`ID` ,`name` ,`password` ,`email` ,`rights`, `IP address`)VALUES (NULL , '$name', '$password', '$email', '1', '$ip');")                       
                        Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.<p>"
                        . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
                        . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p";
                    //--------------------------------------------insert user into db---END-----------------------------------------------------
                    if ($_SESSION['lastpage'])
                    {
                    ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/page<?echo $_SESSION['lastpage'];?>"> <?exit(); //auto return to last page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/login"> <?exit(); //auto return to login page
                    }
                }  //-------------------------------aproved account credentials, insert in db and login---END-------------------------------
            }
            else
            {   
                echo "database selected was not found";
            }
        }   

}
            ?><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mrhowtosay.com/insert"> 
            <a href="insert">insert</a>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: So log the data bots send and try it yourself.

Comment: could you please explain a little more, i don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: log all the `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` and `$_SERVER`. Then check what parameters bots sent to you.

Comment: Solving captchas can be bought! It costs 1US-$ per 1000 Captchas, so if you detected 30 accounts being generated by a machine, someone invested 3 cent to annoy you. Pretty cheap. Who's solving them? Low paid workers in the third world. So there are actually humans involved. That's why captchas do not work anymore.

Comment: are you serious? even if its 3 cents, why would someone pay that to create a small amount of spam that accomplishes nothing?

Comment: Find out where the IP addresses are based, and decide if you are willing to block users from that country. For example if you are quite certain no Indian users would be interested legitimately in your service, but you are getting a lot of requests from India, block IP addresses that originate from there. It's a bit of a sledgehammer, but it will work.

Comment: Spam works different from what you'd usually think. It isn't about "someone spent 3 cent to create 30 accounts on your site to send YOU spam", it's more like "someone spent 100$ to create 100.000 accounts on various sites to send spam, and you got a tiny amount of it." Not all blogs, forums and wikis are actively managed and get spam removed. These that don't are interesting.